# how to convert json to array

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have my Input as below.

```
val inputJson ="""[{"color": "red","value": "#f00"},{"color": "blue","value": "#00f"}]"""
```

I need to convert JSON val to ARRAY
My output should as below.

```
 val colorval=Array("red","blue")
val value=Array("#f00","#00f")
```

Please Kindly Help

Comment: why would you want the solution in apache-spark?

Comment: Why not using this and extract values from list? `import scala.util.parsing.json._
val parsed = JSON.parseFull(<JSON STRING>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following solution should help you if you have large data sets.

```
//input data I guess you have large data
val inputJson ="""[{"color": "red","value": "#f00"},{"color": "blue","value": "#00f"}]"""

//read the json data to dataframe
val df = sqlContext.read.json(sc.parallelize(inputJson::Nil))

//apply the collecting inbuilt functions
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list
df.select(collect_list("color").as("colorVal"), collect_list("value").as("value"))
```

and you should have

```
+-----------+------------+
|colorVal   |value       |
+-----------+------------+
|[red, blue]|[#f00, #00f]|
+-----------+------------+

root
 |-- colorVal: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a DataFrame from the JSON and explode it. Now use collect_list() or collect_set() depending upon whether you need duplicates or not.